# How do I patch a hole in the slab under a kitchen island?

Tags: mold, smell, subfloor

This is one step further than [How do I remove musty smell in coat closet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/how-do-i-remove-musty-smell-in-coat-closet).

There was a sewage backflow under my kitchen island :( I fixed that problem, but now there's a musty smell in one of the island's drawers.

I removed the built-in stove so I can see the sewage and the subfloor, broke one slab and removed 2 buckets of sand beneath the subfloor around the sewage pipe where the dampness had been. I've now been airing it for a week (I also put a small heater there).

NOW: do I just put new sand, and put the stove back in? Or would you also cover the subfloor hole with a thin layer of cement?

Or is there something else that you would try?

Answer (score 1):

My answer from this question will work for your situation
[How should I finish around this hole in my slab?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26518/how-should-i-finish-around-this-hole-in-my-slab/26522#26522)

Starting at the lowest level:

- vapor barrier (6 mil polyethelene plastic)
- if you have cold winter, you can optioally add an insulation layer: 1" or more of XPS insulation
- Something to cover the plastic (or insulation).  Pea gravel is nice for removability.  Concrete will prevent anything from burrowing (in or out)